# Loading 400+ images from SQL via LINQ

Tags: sql-server, linq

I have a problem with loading 400+ images at the same time via Linq.

All the images are stored binary in the database (this is no up for discussion).

To retrieve them i pull out the unique ID's and send the to the browser.
I have a .ashx-handler that takes the ID and returns the image as jpeg-data.

So in the markup i'll just put

```
<img id="img" src='/GetWebImage.ashx?id=<%= Model.Id %>' />
```

This is causing me some problems since when i try to load 400+ at the time the SQL server squirks. Hooking Fiddler up i can see that the SQL server returns 404 on the most part of the images, with errors like:

ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is connecting.

or

There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

or

Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed

So I'm guessing that the sql server cant handle all the calls at one time.

Can anybody help me do this correctly?

I need to load 400+ images from a database in one call. Could i load the images (and not just the ID's, and parse tne via the model, and how would i go from a binary System.Drawing.Image to a path in the -tag?

Another solution would be to load the images oner-by-one witj jQuery (and wait for the images to load) and then insert them in the right place afterwerds - but that seems like a very bad approach. So I'm guessing I'm doing something very wrong from the begining here.

#### Update:

Thanks for the good suggestions. I've found out that my handler actually scales the every image with GDS. Not doing that, made the handler serve the images much faster and not fail. So i guess that the SQL Server problems was actually caused by .net not able to scale fast enough.
I was a bit confused since i have another service serving 10.000+ images the same way with no problems.

But I will definitely go for some caching since there is only one unique URL for every image. **Any suggestions for a Cache?**

For future projects with many images I'll go for storing a path for the image and keep it in the file system. Then the IIS will be the limit of serving the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid out of memory exceptions for large images or multiple calls to the DB, stream the images using this code:

```
 /// <summary>
 /// Writes the binary data at the specified data record index to a stream using a buffer.
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name="source">The source.</param>
 /// <param name="stream">The stream to write to.</param>
 /// <param name="index">The index in the data record to read from.</param>
 /// <remarks>
 /// The data is read sequentially.
 /// </remarks>
 public static void WriteToStream(IQueryable<Binary> source, Stream stream, int index)
 {
     var cmd = DbContext.GetCommand(source);
     cmd.Connection.Open();
     try
     {
         using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
         {
             while (reader.Read())
             {
                 using (var recordStream = new DataRecordStream(reader, index))
                     recordStream.CopyTo(stream);
            }
         }
     }
     finally
     {
         cmd.Connection.Close();
     }
 }
```

And here is the DataRecordStream class that wrapps a dataReader and makes in behave like a stream:

```
public class DataRecordStream : Stream
{
    #region Fields

    private long _position;
    private bool _isOpen; 

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return _isOpen; }
    }

    public override bool CanSeek
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public IDataRecord DataRecord { get; private set; }

    public int Index { get; private set; } 

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="DataRecordStream"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dataRecord">The data record.</param>
    /// <param name="index">The index in the data record to read from.</param>
    public DataRecordStream(IDataRecord dataRecord, int index)
    {
        DataRecord = dataRecord;
        Index = index;
        _position = 0;
        _isOpen = true;
    } 

    #endregion

    #region Functions

    public override void Flush()
    {
    }

    public override long Length
    {
        get { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    }

    public override long Position
    {
        get
        {
            return _position;
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
        _isOpen = false;
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        if (!_isOpen)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("Stream is closed");

        int bytesRead = (int)DataRecord.GetBytes(Index, _position, buffer, offset, count);
        _position += bytesRead;
        return bytesRead;
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    } 

    #endregion
```

Answer (score 2):

You should really use Caching for this kind of thing.

Comment: Any specific suggestions for caching images on a unique url as key?

Answer (score 1):

For caching just add this code to your handler:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may look into

> MARS (Multiple Active Resultsets) [MARS](http://dotnetslackers.com/ASP_NET/re-5946_What_is_MARS_Multiple_Active_Resultsets.aspx)

with     "Asynchronous Processing = true"   in your connection string.
Hope this shall help.